# How to detect and logout idle user from server side in Angular 2 Meteor?

Tags: javascript, angular, meteor, angular2-meteor

I am new to Angular 2 Meteor. I am implementing a project in which I have to logout the user when he closes his window; and again, when he opens the app, he should see the login page.

I searched the internet but didn't find anything for Angular 2 Meteor.

https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status
I found this but I don't know how to use it in Angular 2 case for logout user. where to put this code in server side in Angular 2 Meteor and how to logout the user.

```
Meteor.users.find({ "status.online": true }).observe({
  added: function(id) {
  },
  removed: function(id) {
  }
});
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented this in one of my project you can logout from server side in angular 2 meteor using mizzao/meteor-user-status package. this is what you have to do

**step 1)**   *first of all install this package*

```
meteor add mizzao:user-status
```

**step 2)** *after installing this your users collection table show you some new entry with basic account info. now your json file have some extra keys*

```
 {
    "_id": "uxuhCgmCg6wkK795a",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2016-09-30T05:54:07.414Z"
    },
    "services": {
        "password": {
            "bcrypt": "$2a$10$AxCqCcNsZzdtHSxB9ap9t.KY9kjV2E/U0woF4SFPRBqUD8Bj0XpuO"
        },
        "resume": {
            "loginTokens": [{
                "when": {
                    "$date": "2017-01-09T05:50:17.784Z"
                },
                "hashedToken": "XHpxCKS/kUALKyXCANDBHrJXRV9LAsmCBOOWwmUhAaU="
            }]
        }
    },
    "username": "jhon",
    "emails": [{
        "address": "jhon@gmail.com",
        "verified": false
    }],
    "status": {
        "online": true,
        "lastLogin": {
            "date": {
                "$date": "2017-01-09T05:50:19.055Z"
            },
            "ipAddr": "127.0.0.1",
            "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/49.0.2623.108 Chrome/49.0.2623.108 Safari/537.36"
        },
        "idle": false
    },
    "resume": {
        "loginTokens": []
    }
}
```

step 3) *user-status code on server side*

```
           import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

           Meteor.startup(() => {
               // load initial Parties
               Meteor.users.find({
                   "status.online": true
               }).observe({
                   added: function(id: any) {
                       // id just came online
                       console.log("--------- New User Login ---------");
                       console.log("user " + id.username + " (" + id._id + ") is online now");

                   },
                   removed: function(id: any) {
                       // id just went offline
                       console.log("----------- User idle --------------");
                       console.log("user " + id.username + " (" + id._id + ") is gone offline");
                       // ** use this mongodb query to remove user who go offline from server side 
                       Meteor.users.update({_id: id._id }, {$set: {"services.resume.loginTokens": []} }, { multi: true });
                   }
               });
           });
```

***step 4)*** in client side for login page just put this code

```
ngOnInit() { 
         if (Meteor.user()) { <-- make sure you use Meteor.user() only . if you use Meteor.userId then it can create some issue because it is stored on localhost but Meteor.user() everytime calls server for user data. choice is yours.
             this._router.navigate([//your routename]);
           }
        }
```